# Unable to consume web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, web

I published a simple Hello World web service in an ASP.Net web service project.I closed this project and opened another console based project to consume this web service. The problem is I cannot discover this web service to add reference.When I paste the url, I get the following error

```
    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:65436/Service1.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:65436
```

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, I don't have IIS server installed.

UPDATE- : I created a new Console based project in the existing solution and it works fine.But the problem is how do I run this console project,when I click the debug button, it deploys it on browser.I simply printed the string output returned by web method,I need to see this output on console.

Comment: Whats with downvote,I would like to know. That was a genuine question and I researched over it before asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I closed this project and opened another console based project to consume this web service. The problem is I cannot discover this web service to add reference.

Because the web service is not running. Web service references can only be generated when the metadata is available.

You can either:

- Run two instances of Visual Studio, one for the web service and one for the client
- Put a service and client project in one solution.

Also, you shouldn't use ASMX for new development. Take a look at WCF and WebAPI.

Comment: I created another project in the same solution,but how to run this console project.Please see the UPDATE.

Comment: Right-click your solution and click "Set Startup Projects".

Comment: I am using ASMX thinking it would be the easiest method. Are you saying not to use it because of some security risk? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752213/why-is-asmx-giving-an-error-when-pulling-data-using-client-script. If I want to use WebAPI, is there a beginner tutorial on how to create and run it. I want to host it in IIS so vendor outside our network can access it to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens to me too. I press F5 to start debugging the web service, immediately stop debugging, and then try to update the web reference again. Usually it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy the web service on IIS then consume it in console application.